# Bootstrap Modal Popup Not Clearing old value ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, hidden-field

I have a requirement where i am trying to delete a Customer using Modal PopUp Dialog as confirm delete . If i try to delete Customer 5 it shows ,after closing modal if i click customer 6 it shows me customer 5 only in Modal Popup. When i close Modal how to clear previous Data.`

I am Unable to get the required Id into modal popup ,Im using Hidden field to pass value to Code Behind C# to work with SQL Server.

```
 <div class="modal  fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <center>
                                <input type="text" runat="server"  name="hiddenFieldName" ng-value="{{x.Id}}" id="hiddenFieldName" hidden="hidden" />
                                    <h1>
                                        Are You Sure to Delete Customer  {{x.Id}}</h1>
                                    <p>
                                        Once Deleted ,Customer Information cannot be retreived back, Please Ensure before Deleting.<br />
                                        <b>Customer Name : {{x.VendorName}}</b>
                                    <div id="paymentDueCollapse" class="collapse" style="text-align: justify;">
                                        For your convenience, We have set a quick reminder that Your are currently using
                                        version<b>Purchase/v2.1.1123</b> Last updated on ( date: May 30<sup>th</sup> 2018).
                                        <br />
                                        Please <a href="http://demo.webdrop.in/Quotation Management/bill.htm" target="_blank"
                                            style="color: Orange;"><b>CLICK HERE</b></a> to view the Change Log.
                                        <br />
                                        I hope you have a wonderful rest of the week, and look forward to doing business
                                        with you again soon!
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />

                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" Text="Confirm Delete" CssClass="btn deleteBtnSmall" />
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()"    style="width: 200px;" class="Close Buttonquery pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    Cancel Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: might be binding related issue.how x value is getting assigned?

Comment: Yes x is getting values , x.Id is the customer Id x.VendorName is CustomerName

Comment: How you re launching the model. can you add setTimeout() or manually call Change detection to update the DOM?

Comment: Im closing the modal Popup and reloading the Base page .